# Authorization code grant with Socialite setup

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-9, laravel-passport, laravel-socialite

I'm trying to implement an Authorization code grant with Socialite. I'm able successfully to receive users in the callback, but struggling to set up the other part of auth. I've created the personal passport client and received the client ID & Secret in oauth_clients. Whenever I use the `createToken()` I am able to see oauth_access_tokens these tokens with the name of PKCE(which contains the same name as in oauth_client). The $code is taken from the query in the callback, however, the `$response` in the very end is null, any idea why?

```
   public function callbackGoogle()
  {
    // Receive the user credentials from social
    $googleUser = Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();

    // Get the user by email
    $user = User::where('email', $googleUser->email)->first();

    // Create token
    $user->createToken('PKCE')->accessToken;

    // Get query parameter code from callback
    $code = request()->query()['code'];

    // Get client data
    $client = DB::table('oauth_clients')->where('name', 'PKCE')->first();

    $response = Http::asForm()->post('http://localhost:5000/oauth/token', [
      'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
      'client_id' => $client->id,
      'client_secret' => $client->secret,
      'code' => urldecode($code),
      'redirect_uri' => $client->redirect,
    ]);

    // // Receiving null
    dd($response->json());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to exchange an access token from google with your own application.

This does not make sense.

With this line:

```
$googleUser = Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();
```

You have already exchanged the code from the URL with a token from google.

If you want to get an API token for your API, you already did this with

```
$user->createToken('PKCE')->accessToken;
```

You could use

```
$token = $user->createToken('PKCE')->accessToken;
```

Comment: Yeah, I got the point later that I'm mixing these 2 things into one. Read in some article that Google callback returns access and refresh tokens, can't find via which property, maybe you know?